# Remove [ and ] from excerpt

Tags: excerpt

I am displaying the wordpress posts on the index page with:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

In my functions.php file I have following code:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');
function my_excerpt_length($length) {
return 30; }
```

This works fine but it shows `[...]` at the end of excerpt. I want to remove these `[` and `]` and instead I want to show only three dots `...` . How can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `excerpt_more` filter hook:

```
function mytheme_excerpt_more( $text ) {
    $text = '...';
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'mytheme_excerpt_more' );
```